# How to open multi task window 5.1?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I have Karbonn Quattro L50 with Android 5.1 mobile.  Then i have to open another app. Cant find Multi task window options. When i open a app and to open other app i have to go back back until its on main screen. But cant find the option to switch between both app. Any suggestion or help where can i find the option to switch between multiple apps.

Comment: Do you mean recent apps list?

Comment: Do you have 3 buttons on bottom of the phone or screen when its unlocked, buttons have triangle, circle and square on it?

Comment: yes i cant find recent app list. 1 app at a time i access. Is there any option uncheck or how can i use all the recent apps which are open. Thanks